# Unicode problems in Mini Lyrics

Tags: text-editing, unicode

*Shri guru granth sahib ji* is epic granth for sikhs.

I am working on the project for creating karaoke of guru granth sahib. I am using [Mini Lyrics](http://www.crintsoft.com/) for this for synchronizing speech to text. But this granth is written in gurmukhi(like punjabi). Although mini lyrics support unicode and I found unicode a *guru granth sahib ji* pdf. But when I copy paste the text from the pdf on to the mini lyrics(lyrics editor), it shows some extra characters.

You can also think of this problem as the language other than English in mini lyrics and some problem occurs (some special characters come in to play).

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: what os? iirc unicode support for indian languages on XP is a bit flaky, least for tamil

Comment: windows server.

Comment: windows server what? 2000, 2003 or 2008?

Comment: windows server 2008